# Arreglos de bytes no coinciden entre c# y en nodejs

Tags: c#, nodejs

El problema es el siguiente, tengo esta porción de código en C# que me genera un token.

```
SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("araña"));
string StringByte = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
Console.WriteLine("bytes :" + StringByte);

//writeline = f686964edf1e0feea8a50cd1352efa94196d6f19bd22ff7abad706ff15852d2e
```

mientras que en nodejs lo intento de la siguiente manera

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('araña','ASCII').digest('hex')

//hash = 2b0231711496dae7e431deb1cc05b714ce1faabc9e742a1c7eb479ccd76ed6df
```

No logro hacerlos coincidir y cabe destacar que el error es solo cuando la palabra clave tiene una 'Ñ', mi código es el de node y el de C# no puede ser modificado, de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Esto se puede deber a que el encoding que usa c# y javascript no es el mismo, javascript utiliza utf16 y c# usa utf8 ( la mayoria de las veces), deberias asegurarte de pasar los strings al mismo encoding antes de pedir sus bytes, porque sino pueden diferir.

Comment: lo hago, ambos los establezco en ascii

Comment: He ejecutado una prueba y resulta que nodejs no ejecuta la transformacion de la misma forma que c#, en c# el string "araña" en ascii dice 61-72-61-3F-61 mientras que en nodejs es 61 72 61 f1 61, las soluciones que se me ocurren son 1- cambiar el encoding por otro o 2 - reemplazar todos los caracteres especiales por otros en comun(UTF8 no presenta este problema).
Adjunto la prueba que realice https://pastebin.com/u1cGq3Vy

Comment: @Sacha 1.- el encoding de C# no lo puedo cambiar debido a que es un ejemplo de un web service, yo solo puedo manipular el codigo de nodejs y 2.- el problema es que los tokens se generaran automaticamente con los nombres de los empleados de una empresa, por lo que no puedo evitar las 'Ñ', ya que asi me lo requieren

Comment: Haciendo pruebas encontre que c# convierte todos los caracteres especiales en el caracter '?' ( ascii 63) tal vez la unica solucion posible sea reemplazarlos a la hora de convertir el string en bytes en el node. Siendo que no podes tocar el codigo en c#

Comment: @Sacha hice la prueba y es correcto suplantando la 'Ñ' por un '?' el token se genera correctamente y es igual al de C#, pon tu comentario como respuesta para poder marcarlo como la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo pruebas encontre que c# convierte todos los caracteres especiales en el caracter '?' ( ASCII 63 ).
Tal vez la unica solucion posible sea reemplazarlos a la hora de convertir el string en bytes en el node, Siendo que no podes tocar el codigo en c# y realmente el conjunto de caracteres ASCII comprende menos elementos que el UTF8

Comment: Por supuesto que ASCII comprende menos caracteres que UTF8. UTF8 es una representación Unicode en la que se puede representar cualquier caracter de cualquier alfabeto incluido en el estándar. Hay caracteres que tomarán más de una posición para su representación. ASCII, por otro lado, no puede representar más que 127 caracteres y ASCII extendido, solamente 255. De allí todo el relajo de los códigos de página y esos inventos pre-unicode.

Comment: Claro, el problema esta en que como no podemos establecer una biyeccion entre ambos conjuntos, va a haber una perdida a la hora de pasar del mas grande al mas chico, y al hacer eso ambos lenguajes no estan de acuerdo en como lo hacen